# Graphing two equations simultaneously

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to graph these two equations on one graph, but I keep getting errors.

$S(p)   = −800 + 50 p$

and

$D(p)   = 1900−40p$

I know that these are pretty basic questions, but please bear with as I'm new to the program and I've gone over the intro and manual.

Comment: You've posted a number of these simple questions by now, so here's some general advice. (1) For learning *Mathematica*, the documentation is extremely helpful. If you look up `Plot`, the second example under the `Examples' heading shows you how to plot two functions together in one plot. Use the documentation! Many of your questions are likely to be closed due to being able to be easily found in the documentation. (2) It is helpful for us to see what you've tried. When you say things like "but I keep getting errors", it doesn't help, because we don't know what errors you're getting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
s[p_] := -800 + 50 p
d[p_] := 1900 - 40 p
Plot[{s[p], d[p]}, {p, 0, 50}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Comment: Also, the documentation [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) provides the same solution.